# how can i do a join between two classes with parse PHP SDK

Tags: php, parsing, sdk

everyone,
I have a database in sashido which I attack with parse sdk with php.
I have two related tables, users and hunt, hunt is the one that has the external key to users.
I need to access the data of users who meet certain conditions in hunt, for example that the status of hunt is equal to SCORED.
The query relational is :

Select * from user, hunt where hunt.status = "SCORED" and user.id = hunt.user_id

I dont know how to do queries with two classes, anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN`.

example:

```
 SELECT user*,hunt* form user INNER JOIN hunt on(user.id = hunt.user_id ) 
 where hunt.status = "SCORED"
```

Comment: I know, this is the relational query, i need the query based on classes.
$query = new ParseQuery("Hunt");
$query->equal("status","scored");
$query->includeKey("user"); //is the external key
$results = $query->find(true);

Well, we have the results where status is equal to SCORED, then i need the values of the users related with these results.